# how to use js validator for two different forms in laravel?

Tags: laravel, jsvalidation

how to use js validator rules for two different forms in laravel ?

given below the code in controller

```
private $rules = [
    "remark" => "required",
    "tender_doc_path" => "required",
   ];

private $messages = [        
    "remark.required" => "The Remark Field is required.",
    "tender_doc_path.required" => "The Tender Doc Path Field is required.",
];
```

this rules are used for two different form how it should be conditioned , the tender doc 
   filed is not required for second form

```
  public function appoint_agency_edit($id)
{
     $validator = \JSValidator::make($this->rules,$this->messages);
     return view('ree.architect.appoint_agency',compact('validator'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two instances of your validator. Make sure you pass the rules for each instance properly.

```php
private $rules = [
    'sampleOne' => [
        "remark" => "required",
        "tender_doc_path" => "required",
    ],
    'sampleTwo' => [
        "remark" => "required",
        "tender_doc_path" => "required",
    ]
];

private $messages = [        
    'sampleOne' => [
        "remark.required" => "The Remark Field is required.",
        "tender_doc_path.required" => "The Tender Doc Path Field is required.",
    ],
    'sampleTwo' => [
        "remark.required" => "The Remark Field is required.",
        "tender_doc_path.required" => "The Tender Doc Path Field is required.",
    ]
];

public function appoint_agency_edit($id)
{
     return view('ree.architect.appoint_agency', [
        'sampleOne' => \JSValidator::make($this->rules['sampleOne'], $this->messages['sampleOne'),
        'sampleTwo' => \JSValidator::make($this->rules['sampleTwo'], $this->messages['sampleTwo'])
     ]);
}
```

Comment: yes, this way it will work but the code should be duplicated its not good coding standard 
can there is other way to conditioned only rules for specific form

Comment: Then you should extend your JSValidator so you can use FormRequest.